# Typescript compile error: index.ts(1,5): error TS1005: ';' expected

Tags: typescript

I created the 'index.ts' file and added the next code inside:

```
let x:string = "hello world";

console.log(x);
```

I try to compile it by console command through folder */c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/2.3*

> tsc 'C:\Users\ukhadakouski\Desktop\lesson1\index.ts'

Does anybody know how i can solve it ?

Comment: Guess you need to give us some more info. E.g. do you have a `tsconfig`?

Comment: @SebastianSebald I thought tsconfig was ignored when you gave tsc an explicit filename.

Comment: @SebastianSebald I used the old version of ty (1.0.0.1), I reinstalled typescript using NPM and it works, thanks.